# How to put a vertical rule between buttons in HTML

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to put a vertical rule between two buttons in html.

It should separate the buttons, but instead it is moving the button down.

This

[image]

Turns into this:

[image]

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" >button</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-right: 100px">button </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >separate button</button>
```

for the horizontal rule: `<hr width="1" size="500">`

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/37topjh1/

Comment: The hr tag is not supported by HTML 5, if this is the only place you want a line on your page, I suggest giving one of a buttons a larger margin and adding a border-left / border-right to represent this horizontal rule.

Comment: This isn't strictly true, the `hr` tag is indeed supported in HTML5, however you cannot use inline styling on it. You can do all the same things as HTML4, by adding a class, and applying styling to the class. It's still perfectly valid in HTML5. - https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/hr.html

Comment: @Benneb10 I like the idea of using border-right on the second button. But will adding a margin move the border or just move the button? Would you mind showing an example?

Answer (score 3):

By default, horizontal rules are block elements, so you will need to set the `display` property of the `hr` to `inline-block`. You'll probably also want everything to be aligned nicely in which case you will also need to set the `vertical-align` property of all the elements to `middle`.

```css
button,hr{
  vertical-align:middle;
}
button:nth-of-type(2){margin-right:100px;}
hr{
  background:#000;
  border:0;
  color:#000;
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  width:1px;
}
```

```html
<button>button</button>
<button>button</button>
<hr>
<button>separate button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `display` to `inline-block`:

```
hr {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use inline: block;

```
hr {
  display: inline-block;
}
```